# issue with data from array using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a pie chart that shows data from my array. I also generated a new array from the data but it is not mapping correctly. How do I make the chart display either the people's jobs on it. The legend should possible be a list of set of jobs (Dentist, Teacher, etc) and the graph should show the amount that are dentist, the amount that are teachers, etc or another alternative is age. The legend show the 3 different ages and it maps to the persons name. An example of either of these scenarios would be great.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  newarray:[],
  location:[],
    numbers:[2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3],
    People:[{Name:"Adam", Age:"32",Job:"Dentist"},{Name:"Bill", Age:"22",Job:"Teacher"},{Name:"Peter", Age:"42",Job:"Dentist"}]
  },
  mounted:function () {
  this.newarray = this.People.map(obj => Object.entries(obj)[1]);

  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
      console.log([...new Set(this.People.map(p => p.Job))]);
    },
    mounted:function(){
      this.toggle();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.7.2/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartkick@0.5.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Function:</h2>

<pie-chart :data="newarray" legend="bottom"></pie-chart>
<br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a data member to track 'Name' or 'Job'
2. Use a computed property to calculate the items.  You don't need a data member for the items.
3. Finally, you should use a groupBy function to calculate the group counts.

```js
function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
  const map = {};
  list.forEach((item) => {
    const key = keyGetter(item);
    const collection = map[key];
    if (!collection) {
      map[key] = [item];
    } else {
      collection.push(item);
    }
  });
  return map
}


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    field: 'Age',
    location: [],
    numbers: [2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3],
    People: [{
      Name: "Adam",
      Age: "32",
      Job: "Dentist"
    }, {
      Name: "Bill",
      Age: "22",
      Job: "Teacher"
    }, {
      Name: "Peter",
      Age: "42",
      Job: "Dentist"
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.field = this.field == 'Job' ? 'Age' : 'Job'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      let byGroup = groupBy(this.People, it => it[this.field])
      return Object.entries(byGroup).map(en => ([en[0], en[1].length]))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.7.2/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartkick@0.5.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Function:</h2>
  <button @click='toggle'>Toggle</button>
  <h3>By {{field}}</h3>
  <span v-for='row of rows' style='margin:10px;'>{{row[0]}}:{{row[1]}}</span>
  <pie-chart :data="rows" legend="bottom"></pie-chart>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I want the chart to display for person...for instance. The array would have more entires with same name but have a reviewer. How do I fit 3 objects on 1 chart. people:[{Name: 'Michael John', score:'22',reviewer:'self'},
 {Name: 'Michael John', score:'42',reviewer:'friend'},
        {Name: 'Michael John', score:'10',reviewer:'lead'},
        {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'12',reviewer:'self'},
 {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'22',reviewer:'friend'},
        {Name: 'Zeus Mayho', score:'30',reviewer:'lead'}]

So for Michael: score 42, 10, 12 and mouseover it shows reviewer

Comment: That question concerns mouseover implementation of Chart.js and you should definitely post a new question asking for dataset format related to Chart.js API